# How to show toast when service running on a separate thread?

Tags: android

Is there any way to show a toast when the service is running on a separate thread?
I use the code below.

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid){
    final String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    Log.d(TAG,"onStart()"); 
    new Thread(new Runnable() {


        public void run() {
            try
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ashish 1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"Exception....."+e);
            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: y dont u call toast from service itself?

Comment: you can use a handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toast messages can only shown on uithread. But if you want to use on another thread, you can implement it like this.

```
yourActivityObject.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
        Toast.makeText(yourContextObject, "some text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, method (runOnUiThread)works in a activity then how we can run it inside the another thread?

Comment: Sorry i edited.You should pass an instance of your activity context to your non-activity class.

Comment: it should be `youActivityObject` not `Context`